# How to kill script run through SSH when the local bash script is killed

Tags: ssh, kill, remote, signals

I have the following script called `exec.sh` which runs a python script remotely on node01:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh node01 "python2.7 /home/user/run.py"
```

If I kill `exec.sh` using either `CTRL+C` or `kill -9`, then the python script that I was running through ssh is still executing on node01.

What I want is to kill the process that I was running on node01 whenever I kill the `exec.sh` script.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the exec.sh is local, and it executes a command on a remote machine. So, if you kill the local process, the remote process still runs.

To achieve what you want, you need the exec.sh to catch the SIGNAL of CTRL+C, and before killing itself to kill the command on the remote host.

```
function trap_ctrlc ()
{
# kill the remote process
  ssh user@pass "pkill -9 python"

  exit 2 
}

# initialise trap to call trap_ctrlc function
# when signal 2 (SIGINT) is received
trap "trap_ctrlc" 2

your script here
```

Careful: python is very general process to kill. You better save the process ID when you start it, and then specifically kill it by ID